# Xamarin Android Firebase Cloud Firestore error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying out Firestore with Xamarin.Android.
However, after putting this:

```
 var db = FirebaseFirestore.Instance;
```

It throws an error:

```
FirebaseOptions.getProjectId() cannot be null
```

I have a Google Services JSON with the right build settings, and it has a project id. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see here https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/104.
The bug will be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get your Firebase or Firestore Database Instances. You can find the necessary information needed for this method in your GoogleServices.Json file

```
 public FirebaseFirestore GetDatabase()
    {
        FirebaseFirestore database;

        var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()

             .SetProjectId("YOUR PROJECT ID")
                 .SetApplicationId("YOUR mobilesdk_app_id")
                 .SetApiKey("YOUR API KEY")
                 .SetDatabaseUrl("YOUR firebase_url")
                 .SetStorageBucket("YOUR storage Bucket")
                 .Build();

        var app = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context, options);
        database = FirebaseFirestore.GetInstance(app);

        return database;
    }
```